# A Measure with multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I create a measure in PowerBI for the following scenario:

I want the count of all distinct Ids such that they have event 'Accepted' and 'Timeout'. So in the scenario below I would like to have my Measure return a 2 because of Id 1 and 3. What should be my DAX query?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try and see if this works. (The table is referred to as 'Events'.)

```
Accepted And Timeout Count =
VAR __AcceptedIds = CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( Events[Id] ),
    Events[Event] = "Accepted"
)
VAR __TimeoutIds = CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( Events[Id] ),
    Events[Event] = "Timeout"
)
RETURN 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Events[Id] ),
    INTERSECT ( __AcceptedIds, __TimeoutIds )
)
```

Comment: I get an error: the expression contains multiple columns...

Comment: Something is wrong... "The expression refers to multiple columns..." is raised when a table with 2 or more columns is passed where a scalar value or a single column table is needed. For example, are you sure you are passing only a single column to VALUES?